# JAR Bindings Library issue

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to generate java binding library for this java project material-camera (https://github.com/afollestad/material-camera) the jar files are available on https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven/com/afollestad/material-camera/0.4.4/

unfortunately, the dll is empty, can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to bind that .aar myself, I got one error initially:

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ICameraUriInterface' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Afollestad.Materialcamera.Internal'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234) (MaterialCamera)

Looking in the jar, I see that the java interface `CameraUriInterface` is private, so I changed it to public by adding the following to the MetaData.xml file:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.afollestad.materialcamera.internal']/interface[@name='CameraUriInterface']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

Add the above line between the `<metatdata>   </metadata>` tags. After adding the above the binding built without error and a .dll was created.